# Password for Google Assistant Application created in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

My google assistant app accepts users using gmail account when i linked it with Auth0 but for some reason other email providers are not being connected to the Assistant app. As you can see from the image the first one is the message for a gmail mail id and the second one is for a non gmail mail id.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Abhishek, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what you've already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

No. The [Policies](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#account_linking_and_identity) specifically forbid you from asking for login information in this way.

Instead, you should look into [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/), which will give you information about the user's account which you can use to identify them against an account in your system. You can also use account linking to have more control over the login, auth, and account creation process directly through your website.

Comment: Sorry i actually wanted to ask if i can redirect the user to a web page and then if they could sign in or sign up in that web page and with correct credentials of that website and then be redirected to google assistant and it gives the welcome message saying you have logged in. Something like Auth0 but my website?

Comment: Yes, this is an available option through account linking. I've updated my answer to clarify a little.

Comment: I'm not being able to figure out how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: If you are having problems, please update your question with as many details you can provide - code that you're using, errors that you're getting, etc. We're happy to help, but we do need something to help you with.

Comment: I don't know where to start i just have a brief idea of what i want. I hope you can guide me

Comment: StackOverflow really isn't setup for "guidance" without something to start from. I provided a link to the Account Linking section of the documents. Starting from there is best. If you don't have any action built at all, starting from the codelabs and samples that are posted at that site will be the best starting point.

Comment: I was able to account link with Auth0 and by using a white list rule connect to google accounts. But when i try any other email provider it does not work.

Comment: As I said "please update your question with as many details you can provide". Information in comments doesn't help nearly as much, and isn't as complete. Provide screen shots and examples when you can. The more info you can put into your question, the better our chances are of being able to help.